# is it possible to get HTML of a in browser pdf viewer?

Tags: html, pdf, web-scraping

When you inspect a pdf viewer page in your browser there is a html structure however, both urllib2 and requests return nothing and BS4 goes into an infite loop.

I just want the title (in the head) of the page.

example page:
http://victoria.lviv.ua/html/fl5/NaturalLanguageProcessingWithPython.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Mozilla's pdf.js, you should be able to do this [via the PDF.js API, as detailed in this Issue.](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/669)

```
pdf.info.get('Title')
```

or

```
new Metadata(pdf.catalog.metadata)
metadata.get('dc:title')
```

Comment: I'm currently using python. Was hoping to get the title from the head tag, but I can't seem to get the html structure. I'm not familar with PDF.js.